# How to install MongoDB C++ driver on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm trying to install MongoDB C++ driver in Ubuntu and I just tried to follow [the instructions on MongoDB's site](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/cpp/client/).

I get an error during the `make` and `sudo make` steps. What can I do?

Comment: What instructions did you follow, and what was the problem with them? Did you get an error? Would you add this into the question?

Comment: I'm trying to follow the instructions of mongodb's site https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/cpp/client/

Comment: Right. And what problem did you run into? How far did you get?

Comment: I get an error during the make and sudo make steps.

Comment: Err, OK. And what is that error? Please add that into the question. (All of this information is best provided in the first edit, rather than needing several rounds of enquiry to get it added - worth bearing in mind for future questions. Remember that we cannot see your console or know what problems you are experiencing).

Comment: When I follow these steps:Build and install the C++ driver 1.Clone the repository. 
git clone -b master https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver
2.Build the driver. Note that if you installed the cdriver to a path that is automatically searched by pkgconfig, you can omit the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. 
cd mongo-cxx-driver/build
[PKG_CONFIG_PATH=CDRIVER_INSTALL_PATH/lib/pkgconfig] cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local, then I get this error "make: invalid opcion -- 'D'"

Comment: What is the exact CMake invocation you typed? Please *edit your question* with that information, rather than adding another comment

Comment: I've typed this invocation cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local

Comment: @AntonioRicardoCdiv, would you [edit these changes into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33193174/edit), and then delete the comments of the items you have added? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I leave the link for downloading the driver:

Visit https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/tree/master

In this link you find a tutorial on how to install the driver called the wikki See page